# Regular expression - for email spam filtering, match email address variants other than the original

Tags: regex

I am a email spam quarantine administrator and I can write regular expression rules to block email messages. There is a common classification of email spam hitting our domain such that the username of any of our email addresses is spoofed in front of some other domain.

For example, suppose my email address is jwclark@domain.com. In that case, spammers are writing to me from all kinds of other domains that start with my username such as:

```
jwclark1234@whatever.com
jwclark@wrongdomain.com
jwclark@a.domain.com
```

How can I write a regular expression rule to match everything including jwclark and any wildcards, but not match the original jwclark@domain.com? I would like a regex that matches everything above except for my actual example email address jwclark@domain.com.

Comment: The right way to validate email addresses is using 3rd parties APIs. A few examples: [this](https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/),  [this](http://verify-email.org/using-api.html) and [this](https://tools.email-checker.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made this regexp [here](http://regex101.com/r/eI5cJ0/2)

`^jwclark.*[@](?!domain\.com).*$`

it's in javascript format, but it should be easy to adapt to php or something else.

Given the nature of your problem, you might be better off making a regex builder function that makes the proper regexp for you, given the parameters.

Or, actually use a different approach. I recently found out how to parse ranges of floating point numbers with regexp, but that doesn't make it the proper solution to finding numbers within ranges. :P

edit - fixed silly redundancy thanks to zx81

edit - change to comply with strange limitations:

`^jwclark.{0,25}[@][^d][^o][^m][^a][^i][^n].{0,25}\.com.{0,25}$`

[demo for the strange one](http://regex101.com/r/eI5cJ0/3)

Comment: +1 for correct use of anchors, but I'd suggest replacing the `[@]{1}` with just `@`

Comment: No worries, actually since we're talking, instead of the `.*` my preference in this situation would be `[^@]*@` which uses contrast (mutually exclusive tokens) and doesn't require backtracking, unlike the `.*` But your solution works! Just some potential tweaks for your consideration.

Comment: @zx81 The only thing that worries me about `[^@]*@` is that `.*` won't capture newlines, but perhaps `[^@]` will? Not sure. Not even sure if it matters. I prefer the logic of `[^@]*@`, but it's just that detail that might make me keep `.*` over it.

Comment: You're right that `[^@]` matches line breaks. Hadn't realized we were dealing with multi-line input. In that case `[^@\r\n]` would be an option. (Or what you have!)

Comment: @zx81 I don't think we're dealing with multiline input _per se_, however, since this is supposed to be parsing spammer email addresses, it is possible a malicious spammer could insert an escaped newline in there to block the regex from parsing the string (I don't know how that would help them, or even if it's possible to insert a newline in there, just making assumptions).

Comment: Exposing more details - I went to plug this into our filter at Postini, and their system kicked out an error message as such, "Unlimited ranges are not supported. Use {min,max} syntax with a maximum of 25 in .*, .*
Assertions starting with (? are not supported in (?!domain\.com)" Have you got any idea how to improve the regex in light of this new constraint?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another form of the regex at the end. It should satisfy the system's range requirements. However, I have no idea what to replace the negative lookahead `(?` with, nor is it clear what exactly _is_ supported if this isn't. What language/regex engine is the server running? Hopefully there'll be a refernce online for it.